# pandas groupby: group rows between checkpoints

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

How do I group all rows between "checkpoints"?

For example, if

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=list('abcdefgh')))
checkpoints = [0, 1.5, 6]
```

how do I get the groups `((0,'a'), (1,'b')) and ((2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'e'), (5,'f')) and ((6, 'g'), (7, 'h'))`?

In my actual use case, the index is a datetime index, and it would be nice if the solution was based on logical comparison rather than index location.

EDIT: checkpoints aren't always subset of index

Answer (score 1):

One options is to create a new series marking the checkpoints and group on that:

```
s = (pd.Series(1, index=checkpoints)
       .reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
       .cumsum()
    )

[list(v['a'].to_dict().items()) for _,v in df.groupby(s)]
```

Out:

```
[[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b')],
 [(2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'e'), (5, 'f')],
 [(6, 'g'), (7, 'h')]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us use `cumsum` create the key then `groupby`

```
out = df.reset_index().agg(tuple,1).groupby(df.index.isin(checkpoints).cumsum()).agg(list)
Out[55]: 
1                    [(0, a), (1, b)]
2    [(2, c), (3, d), (4, e), (5, f)]
3                    [(6, g), (7, h)]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Haven't been clear about this, but in my actual use case I'm using checkpoint dates that are not necessarily in the original index

Comment: In fact, I have explicitly said the opposite. Anyway, if you have an idea for the non-subset case, I'd appreciate it

Comment: Also, and I apologize for failing so bad at creating that MWE, I really have a multi-index, where multiple entries have the same dates, and I want the group by ["date_range", "other_index_level"], which is another reason why your solution doesn't work for me

Comment: I think I figured it out, using unstack and using some uglyness to snap the checkpoints to the closes dates in the index